# Automatically copy inputText maxlength from entity class @Size value

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible to set the `maxlength` attribute of an `<h:inputText>` tag to be the same as its entity class `@Size` max value?

For example, given:

```
@Size(max = 50)
String name;
```

...somehow automatically/programmatically set the number 50 in:

```
<h:inputText id="name" maxlength="50" .../>
```

Comment: @Arjan: yes, you should use extVal, it will do it automatically for you.

Comment: Nice! Care to answer your own question then?

Comment: @Arjan: I answered it, hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [Apache MyFaces Extensions Validator](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/validator/), ExtVal.

[This link](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-bean-validation-together-with.html) and [this link](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/sample_chapters/3254_Apache%20MyFaces_SampleChapter.pdf) explain how to add ExtVal into your project. You need to add the required jars and to add the annotation @MaxLength above the field, and you will see the maxLength inside the html input.

Comment: Or you use @Size which supports the same as soon as you add ExtVal.